# How to solve recurrence T(n) = 5T(n/5) + n/ lgn

Tags: asymptotics, recurrence-relation

It can't be solved with master method. The result seems to be T(n) = Θ (nlg lgn), but I have a problem to prove it. Could you help please?

Comment: In particular, see this answer: https://cs.stackexchange.com/a/86285/683.

Comment: I tried to update Wikipedia so that other people don't face the same problem, but apparently this was too much for the Wikipedia overlords.

Comment: @YuvalFilmus What page? What part of it? Perhaps I can find the patience to go through the process of updating it.

Comment: The article on the master theorem. My latest update has resisted reactionary efforts so far.